# How do I fill correctly the meta tags for Weebly plataform

Tags: html, meta-tags, weebly

I'm developing a website in Weebly platform. I'm having issues with the meta-tags because without them I can't publish/advertise the website on Facebook which is a must for the organization.

So, I have already went to **Settings > SEO** and than added:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.website.com" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.website.com" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.website.com/files/theme/facebook-logo.png"/>
```

Because that didn't work I also added on the **Pages > Index > SEO Settings** the same code excerpt to the header of the page. That also didn't work.

When I go inspect the page on Chrome I verified that there are 3 repetitions of the meta tag

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.website.com" />
```

which one of them is **http**...

What am I missing here? Is Weebly filling out meta tags by default? Is it some mechanism?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Weebly adds Open Graph meta tags for the site automatically and fills them out by default using the information you supply while defining/building your site.

If you want to change the values for these automatically injected, Open Graph meta tags, you will want to change the settings and SEO for your site/pages.